# Does adding optional parameters change method signatures and would it trigger method missing exception?

Tags: c#

We have several projects that are referencing library assembly lets call "myUtil", now one of the method which is referenced in several projects is,

```
GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3, bool p4 = false);
```

Now if I change above method to this,

```
GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3, bool p4 = false, bool p5 = false);
```

**Do I must need to update "myUtil.dll" assembly to projects  referencing it ?**

WIthout referencing it I get this error which does makes sense and goes away when I update reference, **but I am NOT ABLE TO VALID FIND reference where it says you must need to update references**

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void GetData(....

Comment: Please be a bit more clear with what you are asking. It sounds like you have a C# project that has a reference to MyUtil.dll. In side of a completely separate project, you add a new method to MyUtil.dll and recompile it. You then expect MyUtil.dll to magically expose the new method to your first project that references it. Any time you add a method to the .dll project, you must recompile and re-add it to any other projects referencing it.

Comment: If the projects are sharing the same solution, then this would be a different problem. Your question wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Once you rebuild your `myUtil.dll` and your referencing projects point to your new assembly you're good to go.

Comment: @Dunken what am really looking for is a valid reference for it, does adding optional parameter makes it a different method then without one ?

Comment: Yes, adding a new parameter, optional or not, changes the method signature. This requires you to redeploy the reference to the projects referencing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All references must be updated.

Optional parameters are just syntactic sugar.

When you have this:

```
GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3, bool p4 = false);
```

And call it like this:

```
GetData(1, "p2", obj);
```

The compiler does this:

```
GetData(1, "p2", obj, false);
```

You'll need to recompile and redeploy all assemblies/projects that reference it.

Comment: Thanks Brendan for confirmation, Would you like to add a valid reference please as I couldn't find one myself

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to remove and re-add the reference, but you *do* need to rebuild all of the projects that compile against the DLL. Adding an optional parameter is a source-compatible but not a binary-compatible change, because the compiler emits different IL at the *call* site, to include the default value as normal - the call itself looks the same in the IL whether the optional parameter was omitted or not.

For example, consider the following code:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(3);
        Foo();
    }

    static void Foo(int x = 5)
    {
    }
}
```

The IL for `Main` looks like this:

```
  .method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       16 (0x10)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_0002:  call       void Test::Foo(int32)
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  ldc.i4.5
    IL_0009:  call       void Test::Foo(int32)
    IL_000e:  nop
    IL_000f:  ret
  } // end of method Test::Main
```

As you can see, the constant 5 is loaded *in the `Main` method* and passed as an argument, just as 3 is explicitly. The same thing happens across assembly boundaries.

The same rules also applies to changing the values of constants, and changing the default value of an optional parameter - all of these require client rebuilds.

Comment: Thanks Skeet, I am struggling to find any valid read or reference for this subject - Does adding optional parameters change method signatures and would it trigger method missing exception ? maybe i am just after a valid reference to keep other developers happy

Comment: @THE: I can't see anything *very* clear in the C# language specification, but yes, the optional parameter is part of the signature. I've updated my answer to give an example of how a call to a method with an optional parameter is compiled, so you can see that the default value is baked into the call site.

Answer (score 4):

You can maintain compatibility if you stop using the optional parameters and use method overloading instead:

```
public void GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3, bool p4 = false, bool p5 = false)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Becomes

```
public void GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3)
{
    GetData(p1, p2, p3, false);
}

public void GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3, bool p4)
{
    GetData(p1, p2, p3, p4, false);
}

public void GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3, bool p4, bool p5)
{
    //Do something
}
```

This however won't reflect a change in the default value unless you recompile all the projects. For example any old `GetData(1, "2", null)` will always call the new `GetData(1, "2", null, false)` even if you change

```
public void GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3)
{
    GetData(p1, p2, p3, false);
}
```

to

```
public void GetData(int p1, string p2, object p3)
{
    GetData(p1, p2, p3, true);
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this coding pattern as it doesnt require a client recompile. (just for the new param add; I realize changing default values does require client recompile)

Comment: ⨥1 for the alternative